# Using Protractor Test Runner from command pallette (VS Code)

Tags: protractor, visual-studio-code

I am new to Protractor. I have have a problem running it from Command Pallette (`Ctrl-Shift-P` or `F1`). I am using: VS Code 1.11.2 and Protractor 5.1.1.

- from the Terminal it works. `protractor protractor/protractor.conf.js`
- from Debug > Launch it works.
- however, when from the View > Command Pallette > Protractor: Run Test(s), i get the error: `**you must either specify a configuration file or at least 3 options. See below for the options:...`

**Folder structure is**

```
..demo
....package.json
....node_modules
....protractor
........protractor.conf.js
........spec.js
```

**protractor.conf.js**

```
exports.config = {  
  framework: 'jasmine',
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome'
  },
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['protractor_selenium.js']
};
```

**spec.js**

```
describe("google show", function(){
    it('should work', function(){
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
        browser.get('https://google.com');            
        //does somethi
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
    });
});
```

**launch.js**

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Protractor Tests",
            "args": ["${workspaceRoot}/protractor/protractor.conf.js"],            
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor/"
        },        
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Attach to Port",
            "address": "localhost",
            "port": 5858
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not Visual Studio Code or ProtractorJS feature, this is implemented by 3rd party plugin (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=luciannaie.protractor-test-runner). Try to reach author on github - https://github.com/lnaie/vscode-protractor-test-runner/issues/

Comment: Thanks. @Xotabu4. I have now done the same. [https://github.com/lnaie/vscode-protractor-test-runner/issues/2](https://github.com/lnaie/vscode-protractor-test-runner/issues/2)